# Why with axum v0.7 the stream is no Sync anymore?

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-axum

Using axum v0.6 I was able to use the below code with the following function:

```rust
pub async fn create_file(
    &self,
    name: &str,
    reader: Pin<Box<(dyn AsyncRead + Send + Sync)>>,
) -> Result<CreatedFile>
```

```rust
// axum's handler
pub async fn upload(stream: BodyStream) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {
    let stream = stream.map_err(|err| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err));

    let res = file_create("filename", Box::pin(StreamReader::new(stream))).await?;

    Ok((StatusCode::CREATED, "Ok").into_response())
}
```

Now with axum v0.7 I'm using this:

```rust
// axum's handler
pub async fn upload(request: Request) -> Result<Response, StatusCode> {
    let stream = request
        .into_body()
        .into_data_stream()
        .map_err(|err| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, err));

    let res = file_create("filename", Box::pin(StreamReader::new(stream))).await?;

    Ok((StatusCode::CREATED, "Ok").into_response())
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0277]: `(dyn axum::body::HttpBody<Data = tokio_util::bytes::Bytes, Error = axum::Error> + std::marker::Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
59  |             Box::pin(StreamReader::new(stream)),
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `(dyn axum::body::HttpBody<Data = tokio_util::bytes::Bytes, Error = axum::Error> + std::marker::Send + 'static)` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Sync` is not implemented for `(dyn axum::body::HttpBody<Data = tokio_util::bytes::Bytes, Error = axum::Error> + std::marker::Send + 'static)`
    = note: required for `std::ptr::Unique<(dyn axum::body::HttpBody<Data = tokio_util::bytes::Bytes, Error = axum::Error> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>` to implement `std::marker::Sync`
note: required because it appears within the type `Box<dyn HttpBody<Data = Bytes, Error = Error> + Send>`
    |
195 | pub struct Box<
    |            ^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `Pin<Box<dyn HttpBody<Data = Bytes, Error = Error> + Send>>`
    |
410 | pub struct Pin<P> {
    |            ^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `UnsyncBoxBody<Bytes, Error>`
    |
17  | pub struct UnsyncBoxBody<D, E> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `Body`
    |
39  | pub struct Body(BoxBody);
    |            ^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `BodyDataStream`
    |
140 | pub struct BodyDataStream {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `IntoStream<BodyDataStream>`
    |
12  |     pub struct IntoStream<St> {
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `Map<IntoStream<BodyDataStream>, MapErrFn<{closure@file.rs:48:18}>>`
    |
15  |     pub struct Map<St, F> {
    |                ^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `MapErr<BodyDataStream, {closure@file.rs:48:18}>`
    |
63  |     MapErr<St, F>(
    |     ^^^^^^
note: required because it appears within the type `StreamReader<MapErr<BodyDataStream, {closure@file.rs:48:18}>, Bytes>`
    |
156 | pub struct StreamReader<S, B> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: required for the cast from `Pin<Box<StreamReader<MapErr<BodyDataStream, {closure@file.rs:48:18}>, Bytes>>>` to `std::pin::Pin<std::boxed::Box<(dyn tokio::io::AsyncRead + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync + 'static)>>`
```

Why?

Comment: Just remove the `Sync` bound from `reader: Pin<Box<(dyn AsyncRead + Send + Sync)>>`. It's useless since `AsyncRead` has no methods that take `&self`.

Comment: Can you please answer so I can accept that? And maybe I can ask you to explain better or send me a link to better understand? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function argument should be changed:

```
reader: Pin<Box<(dyn AsyncRead + Send + Sync)>>,
```

Just remove the `Sync` bound as it's unnecessary.

To understand why it's unnecessary, we first need to understand what `Sync` does.  What `Sync` means is "this type can be accessed using a shared reference by multiple threads safely."  In other words, `&T` is `Send` only if `T` is `Sync`.

For this to matter, the type needs to have methods that take `self` by shared reference (e.g. `&self`).  However, none of the methods of `AsyncRead` do this; they all require an exclusive reference (technically a pinned exclusive reference -- `Pin<&mut self>`).  This means that even if you have a `Pin<&dyn AsyncRead>`, you won't be able to do anything useful with it.  You would need an exclusive reference, and `Sync` is unrelated to exclusive references.

Further reading:

- [Send and Sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html)